# Each time I try the predict method this is what I get: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_16" is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tkinter, keras, tf.keras

I'm trying to train my model to read some x-ray Images, I'm using Jupyter Notebook, I imported the Libraries, Defined the image properties, Prepared the dataset, Created the neural net model, Defined callbacks... and Managed the Data, Trained the model, and I'm using Tkinter as a gui to use the method here's what I get when I press the button to run the method :

> WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128,
> 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 128, 128,
> 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_16_input'), name='conv2d_16_input',
> description="created by layer 'conv2d_16_input'"), but it was called
> on an input with incompatible shape (None, 128, 128).

[image]

And here's my neural network model :

```
model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(Image_Width,Image_Height,Image_Channels)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I've put 3 dimensions into the input_shape, `Image_Width=128` `Image_Height=128` `Image_Channels=3`

Model was constructed with shape (None, 128, 128, 3) for input, I don't see why I get why I get  `expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3` correct me if I'm wrong I'm new into this, Thanks for your time.

Edit: My tkinter gui Code to run the method :

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import numpy
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('C:/Users/lenovo/PneumoniaClassification/pneumoniatest9999_10epoch.h5')
#dictionary to label all traffic signs class.
classes = { 
    0:'Normal',
    1:'Pneumonia',
 
}
#initialise GUI
top=tk.Tk()
top.geometry('800x600')
top.title('Pneumonia Classification')
top.configure(background='#CDCDCD')
label=Label(top,background='#CDCDCD', font=('arial',15,'bold'))
sign_image = Label(top)
def classify(file_path):
    global label_packed
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    image = image.resize((128,128))
    image = numpy.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = numpy.array(image)
    image = image/255
    pred = model.predict([image])[0]
    sign = classes[pred]
    print(sign)
    label.configure(foreground='#011638', text=sign) 
def show_classify_button(file_path):
    classify_b=Button(top,text="Classify Image",
   command=lambda: classify(file_path),
   padx=10,pady=5)
    classify_b.configure(background='#364156', foreground='white',
font=('arial',10,'bold'))
    classify_b.place(relx=0.79,rely=0.46)
def upload_image():
    try:
        file_path=filedialog.askopenfilename()
        uploaded=Image.open(file_path)
        uploaded.thumbnail(((top.winfo_width()/2.25),
    (top.winfo_height()/2.25)))
        im=ImageTk.PhotoImage(uploaded)
        sign_image.configure(image=im)
        sign_image.image=im
        label.configure(text='')
        show_classify_button(file_path)
    except:
        pass
upload=Button(top,text="Upload an image",command=upload_image,padx=10,pady=5)
upload.configure(background='#364156', foreground='white',font=('arial',10,'bold'))
upload.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=50)
sign_image.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True)
label.pack(side=BOTTOM,expand=True)
heading = Label(top, text="Pneumonia Classification",pady=20, font=('arial',20,'bold'))
heading.configure(background='#CDCDCD',foreground='#364156')
heading.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model needs the input shape `(samples, width, height, channels`). So when you call `model.predict`, you should feed an image to your model with the shape `(1, 128, 128, 3)`. This corresponds to the predefined input shape of your model: `input_shape=(Image_Width,Image_Height,Image_Channels)` (excluding the batch / samples dimension). I assume you want to make a prediction for a single image, hence the number 1.

If you are feeding grayscale images to your model, you will have to convert them to `RGB`, for example with `tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb`:

```
model.predict(tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(image))
```

Full working example for reference:

```
import tensorflow as tf

model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32,(3,3),activation='relu',input_shape=(128, 128, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128,(3,3),activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(512,activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

image = tf.random.normal((1, 128, 128, 3))
print(model.predict(image))
```

Comment: I tried what you've said but I receive this Error now :
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "max_pooling2d_20" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=5. Full shape received: (None, 1, 126, 126, 32)

Comment: Same thing when I use model(image),  image = image.resize((128,128)), I'll upload the tkinter code on my question.

Comment: @Sofiane can you run `print(image.shape)` after this line `image = image/255` and show the output?

Comment: here's the output I get : (1, 128, 128)

Comment: Yeah that is your problem..did you read my answer?.. You need the shape `(1, 128, 128, 3)`.. You are missing the channels dimension (3)